# How to temporariliy disable access to Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, maintenance

I would like to be able to temporarily disable all access to an Oracle database, except my own, to be able to perform maintenance actions without interruptions. Simplest way?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this link:

[How to switch Oracle in Single User-Multi Session Mode](http://askanantha.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-switch-oracle-in-single-user.html)

> During a migration it may be important, that nobody can connect to the database. You may have two possibilities to achieve this
>
> On Table Level using LOCK TABLE
>
> On Database Level using RESTRICTED SESSION

Answer (score 3):

See [Quiescing a Database](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm)

## Short:

- `ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE RESTRICTED;`
  puts the Database in quiesce mode
- `ALTER SYSTEM UNQUIESCE;`
  puts the database back in normal operation

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [quiescing the database](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm), there are number of options depending on how you want to deal with users who are presently connected. My favourite technique when I'm in a tight change window is [STARTUP FORCE RESTRICT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12045.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, a more basic solution would be to shutdown the listener.

Comment: This will only work if you have no access from the database server itself. These connections bypass the listener.